Regular Expression to get every run of text separated by fewer than 2 spaces
I am trying to parse some tabular data in a <pre> tag and I am struggling to find the right pattern.  I'd like to sequentially match all runs of characters that are separated by at most one space.
Input: '                                                   Not seasonally adjusted                      Seasonally adjusted (1)                  Latest'
Desired output:
['Not seasonally adjusted', 'Seasonally adjusted (1)', 'Latest']

I tried a negative lookahead '[\S ]+(?!\s{2,})' which gives one match for the entire text line.
I tried a negator '[^\s{2,}]' which matches every non space character in the text line
I tried a .* followed by a negator '.*[^\s{2,}]' which gives one match for the entire text line

NOTE:  I am using python and don't just want to do something like re.split('\s{2,}') because I don't merely want the contained text, but want to preserve the start and end characters of each run of text in order to feed it into a tabular parser/interpreter script.
How can I accomplish this?

Try r'\b[^\b]*?(?=\s{2,}|$)'? Example about your note?

btw, your "negator" doesn't do what you think: re.findall('[^\s{2,}]','{abc, def, 123}')

import re
re.findall("\S+(?: \S+)*", '                                                   Not seasonally adjusted                      Seasonally adjusted (1)                  Latest')

→
['Not seasonally adjusted', 'Seasonally adjusted (1)', 'Latest']


This is a good approach for me.  The idea of using a non-capturing group is what I was missing.  Thanks!

I used   because you wrote "space" but \s might be more correct, if other kinds of whitespace should be handled (or not). e.g. \S+(?:\s\S+)* or [^ ]+(?: [^ ]+)*

Yes, I understood that part.  Thank you.  I ended up using \S(?:(?!\s{2,}).)+ and \S(?:(?!\s{3,}).)+ as a fallback for some of the tables that annoyingly use double spaces in the table headers
